# Mysql Query dont uses primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

- Querycache is disabled!
- Indexes are 100 % loaded in RAM
- index is only ID

1benchmark:

```
"SELECT title FROM posts LIMIT ?, 15";
? = rand(1,183655);

EXPLAIN 
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  posts   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    183637
```

after doing 100 loops it took over 100 sec.

2Benchmark:

```
"SELECT title FROM posts WHERE id = 78845 OR id = 158738 OR id = 57065 OR id = 146797 OR id = 78918 OR id = 65227 OR id = 117987 OR id = 92541 OR id = 39782 OR id = 1958 OR id = 180384 OR id = 170758 OR id = 102227 OR id = 180223 OR id = 46391";

    in each loop every id is generated via rand(1,183655);
```

after doing 100 loops it took 6 sec to finish and it uses the primary key.

The problem is I think in the **LIMIT** MySQL doesn't use the **primary key** for the **id**.

After testing with Limit again:

```
SECONDS:        LOOPS:  SQL:
41.560034990311 =    30 =   "SELECT title FROM posts LIMIT ?, 15";
36.302664995193 =    30 =   "SELECT title FROM posts ORDER BY id LIMIT ?, 15";
70.335160970688 =    30 =   "SELECT title FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ?, 15";
48.453547000885 =    30 =   "SELECT id, title FROM posts LIMIT ?, 15"
```

Somehow but I'm not **100 % sure**. I updated on my VMware **PHP5.1.6 to PHP5.3** since then I noticed, that these LIMIT queries take longer.

Comment: `LIMIT BigNumber, AnyNumber` is known to be slow.

Comment: Correct: LIMIT mysql dont uses the primary key for the id. The query starts producing rows and when it hits the offset row it starts outputing them until row_count is reached. You can try adding an index on title to see if that helps (asuming that index fits into memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run this instead:

```
SELECT title 
FROM posts 
WHERE id >= ?
LIMIT 15
```

It's not equivalent to the `LIMIT ?, 15` but it will use the index.

You can also check this [related article](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/).

Comment: ah thats great!!! thanks! now the query takes 1.5 sec for a 100 loop really thanks!!

Comment: Check the article link I added, too.